# C++ function pointer with string

Tags: c++, function, pointers

In C++, I have many functions (one, two three...) that look like this:

```
int MyClass::one(Mynamespace::Data* data)
{
    //do something
    return 0;
}
```

I also have an action function that I want to use to call one, two, three... functions with a function pointer.

```
int MyClass::action(Mynamespace::Data* data)
{
    int (*actionFunction)(Mynamespace::Data*);
    actionFunction = data->name; // the name is a string with the function name (one, two, three...)
    return (*actionFunction)(data);

}
```

The error I get says:

```
int (MyClass::)(Mynamespace::Data*)’ does not match ‘int (*)(Mynamespace::Data*)
```

What am I doing wrong? If there is another way to do this fast and easy I would like to learn it too.
Thank you

Comment: Google "member function pointer".

Comment: It is clearly saying the types are different, and I know that you know what type `name` actually is, if you have declared the member yourself (and if you have declared it yourself, then you should be able to figure out how `actionFunction` should be declared). So could you let us know how exactly have you declared `name`?

Comment: Thank you for your help. David's and Stewart's answers were very helpful. However, I forgot to mention that MyClass is a base class and one, two, three... functions are overrided in other classes. I've have decided to use an enum and a normal switch case to call them for the moment as pointers gave me problems with that.

Comment: One of the other things that is special about pointers to members is that they handle virtual functions in the way you would expect, so if you have a base class with a virtual method foo, and you take a pointer to member and call it on a derived class which overrides foo, the derived foo will be called even though you took the pointer to member on the base class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a table that maps function names to function addresses. You can use a variable of type
`std::map<std::string, int (MyClass::*)(Mynamespace::Data*)>` to hold it.

The ParaShift C++ faq has [an article on arrays of pointers to member functions](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/array-memfnptrs.html) that you should probably understand completely before attempting this, since this is more complex.

Answer (score 3):

Pointers to non-static member functions in C++ are different to pointers to standalone functions. This is because non-static member functions must have a this pointer passed to them implicitly when they are called.

As a result of this, you cannot assign a pointer to a member function to a regular function pointer. The compiler is telling you this, but in a complicated way. What the compiler is saying is that you are trying to assign a value of type:

```
int (MyClass::)(Mynamespace::Data*)
```

which is how you spell the type of a pointer to a non static member of MyClass to a variable of type

```
int (*)(Mynamespace::Data*)
```

Which is how you spell the type of a regular function pointer.

To fix it, you should change the definition of `actionFunction` to the following

```
int (MyClass::* actionFunction)(Mynamespace::Data*)
```

Which declares a member function pointer, and then when you call through the pointer on the return line you should use the member-function operator to call it like so:

```
return (this->*actionFunction)(data);
```